# Easiest way to synchronize a number of SQLite databases

Tags: php, android, database, sqlite, xampp

I created a mobile application with a SQLite database. However, now I need this database to be updated on a server rather than just the device itself as it will be used by a number of users. Is there an easy way to do this or is the best option to create a new database using PHP?